# Asp.Net Core Mvc 2.0 view page error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I get such an error after adding a new controller

> An error occurred while starting the application. TypeLoadException:
>   Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DirectiveDescriptorBuilder' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.InjectDirective..cctor()
>   TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.InjectDirective' threw an
>   exception.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.InjectDirective.Register(IRazorEngineBuilder
>   builder)
>
> ```
> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DirectiveDescriptorBuilder' from
> ```
>
> assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

```
public class Startup { 
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) 
    { 
       Configuration = configuration; 
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // DbContext Ayarları
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyWorldContext");
        services.AddDbContextPool<MyWorldContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddMvc();

        //  services.AddSingleton<MyWorldContext>();  


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, MyWorldContext context)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        //  app.UseMvc();

        Initializer.MyInitialize(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the error details? Just pasting an image doesn't help much. That's why we don't allow new users to embed them in their questions. We'll also need any related code.

Comment: Sorry, I get such an error after adding a new controller

Comment: Do you mean the error is occurring within Visual Studio, or when you try to open a view? If the latter, please post your Startup class, controller, and view.

Comment: Controller and view, standart home/index

Comment: I get this error when I open the page after adding a new controller to the project